# No such property for Jenkins while running groovy script from command line

Tags: groovy, jenkins-scriptler

Using script console I'm able to execute the below script without any issues. However whenever I run the script from command line I got the below error. Added a "**Execute Groovy script**" to the job throwing the same error. "**Execute system Groovy script**" works fine. Is there anything wrong I'm doing? Can somebody help me plz

```
import  jenkins.model.Jenkins.*;
jenkins = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance

def item = jenkins.getItem("3rd-libraries")
def build = item.getLastBuild()

println build.isInProgress()

Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: jenkins for class: job
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: jenkins for class: job
        at job.run(job.groovy:2)
```

Jenkins:2.18

Groovy: Groovy Version: 2.4.6 JVM: 1.7.0_40 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing the `def` declaration for jenkins.

The second line should read;

```
def jenkins = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance
```

Comment: such a silly mistake. Thank you so much @Domhnaill Byrne :)